# Separate range values from datepicker in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this library `semantic-ui-calendar-react`, it works great but it return a string inside an object like so :

> {datesRange: "20190504 - 20190522"}
>
> **proto**: Object

```
        <DatesRangeInput
          allowSameEndDate={true}
          dateFormat='YYYYMMDD'
          popupPosition='bottom left'
          name="datesRange"
          placeholder="From - To"
          value={this.state.datesRange}
          iconPosition="left"
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
        />
```

In this app I'll need those values separate like startDate and endDate, I know I can use regex or something like that to extract it but that's too much code, there must be a an easy way using this library, I couldn't find anything in the docs.

I tried this so far, not working

```
 console.log(this.state.datesRange.split(" ",3) );
```

As a quick fix I am using two separate `DateInput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first split the date string with delimiter `-` This will create an array like `["20190504 ", " 20190522"]`. Next create a function which will return this string in a format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Since `new Date('20190504')` will give null unless it is formatted in a acceptable standard. `trim()` is to remove ant white space from the string

```js
let dt = {
  datesRange: "20190504 - 20190522"
}
let rng = dt.datesRange.split('-');
let startDate = new Date(convertToDateFormat(rng[0].trim()));
let endDate = new Date(convertToDateFormat(rng[1].trim()));
console.log(startDate, endDate)

function convertToDateFormat(dt) {
  return `${dt.slice(0,4)}-${dt.slice(4,6)}-${dt.slice(6,8)}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this format is guaranteed, you can get those values using split function as you guessed. Just use a different splitter string like this:

```
this.state.datesRange.split(" - ")
```

this code will return an array. With your example it will return `["20190504", "20190522"]`